# Sudoku solving/generating algorithm issue

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sudoku

I am creating a program that will generate sudoku puzzles in vb.net, and due to the way I am doing this I require it to solve a board position (accessing the cells in a specific, random order) and then to solve it again in reverse order. I am using a recursive solver for this.

This is the code I am working with:

```
Public Function solve(ByRef board() As Integer) As Boolean
    For i = 0 To 80
        If board(order(i)) = 0 Then
            For j = 1 To 9
                board(order(i)) = j
                If check_conflicts(board, order(i)) = False Then
                    If solve(board) = True Then
                        Return True
                    End If

                End If
            Next
            board(order(i)) = 0
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

where `check_conflicts` is a function that determines whether  a particular cell assignment directly conflicts with the board (hence the board is passed and the index of the cell `order(i)` is also passed). This function works as expected when the `order` is a list of 0 to 80, however if `order` is a randomly shuffled list then the function takes incredibly long (sometimes upwards of a minute) but usually gets the correct answer. When order is a list of numbers from 80 to 0, the function does not solve anything and always returns false.

I have tried stepping through the code but it is difficult with a recursive function. I wonder if anybody can see a logical error I have made, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function works as expected when the order is a list of 0 to 80,
>   however if order is a randomly shuffled list then the function takes
>   incredibly long (sometimes upwards of a minute) but usually gets the
>   correct answer.

The reason may be that while the recursion tree grows exponentially with the recursion depth, when you process the numbers row by row (rather than in a random order), most of the invalid arrangements are cut out early. You'll never have to process the second row with the first row being inconsistent.

> When order is a list of numbers from 80 to 0, the function does not
>   solve anything and always returns false.

A couple suggestions:

1) Try replacing `order(i)` with `80-i` to make sure the problem is not in the `order()` function;

2) Every time you call `check_conflicts(board, order(i))`, call also `check_conflicts(inverse(board), 80-order(i))` and throw an exception if their results are not equal.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried your suggestions and realised the reason it did not work backwards was because of an error in the constraint sets that made the puzzle impossible. I have suspected the same thing about the algorithm being inherently slow, guess I need to implement some optimizations